# Program doesn't see matrix and complex numbers. Is that importing library problem?

Tags: python

I don't know how to make matrix and complex numbers visible for the program. It is problem with library or bad.There are errors like: name 'I' is not defined or 'matrix'is not defined. Thank you in advance for help - I'm a total beginner in python.

```
import cmath
import numpy
a=7
b=-2*I
c=2*I
d=81

A=matrix(QQbar,6,6)
for i in range(0,6):
    A[i,0]=a**i
    A[i,1]=b**i
    A[i,2]=c**i
    A[i,3]=d**i
    A[i,4]=d**i*i
    A[i,5]=d**i*i*i
    A[0,6]=7
    A[1,6]=8
    A[2,6]=-7
    A[3,6]=1

print(A)

h=0
k=0

while h <6 and k <7:
    maxElement=0
    for z in range(0,6):
        if abs(A[h,z])>maxElement:
            maxElement=abs(A[h,z])
            i_max=z
            if A[i_max,k]==0:
                k=k+1
            else:
                A.swap_rows(h,i_max)
                for y in range(h+1,6):
                    f=A[i,k]/A[h,k]
                    A[i,k]=0
                    for j in range(k+1,7):
                        A[i,j]=A[i,j]-A[h,j]*f
                    print(A)
                h=h+1
                k=k+1
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,i):
        multiply=-A[j,i]/A[i,i]
        A.add_multiple_of_row(j,i,multiply)
        print(A)

x1=A[0,6]/A[0,0]

print(x1)
```

Comment: `b=-2*I` What is the `I`?

Comment: `cmath` imaginary part is `1j`. A number followed by a j.

Comment: Convert `matrix` to `np.matrix`. But, What is `QQbar`?

Comment: I am writing in sage and that's from the article :

Comment: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/constructor.html

Comment: Whole matrix in jupyter works, but  whole code doesn't work and doesn't show errors.

Comment: converting matrix to np.matrix doesn't help

Comment: When you do `import numpy`, you introduce *exactly one name* into your namespace: `numpy` itself.  Elements of that module would then be referred to as `numpy.matrix` for example.  Or, you could do something like `from numpy import matrix` and be able to refer to `matrix` directly.

Comment: in sage's documentation is [standalone-python-sage-scripts](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/programming.html#standalone-python-sage-scripts). It uses `from sage.all import *` . It also run it with `sage`, not `python` - see `#!/usr/bin/env sage`

Comment: thank you for Your answers! I did it ;)